# Sql Help - Not Contains Total Product Count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

[image]

I use sql server and, I try to get that result:

[image]

It means: According to Orders

There is no total 4 order in Asus

There is no total 5 order in Dell

There is no total 3 order in Sony

I need to match `CompanyProducts.P_Name like '%' + Orders.O_Name + '%'`

Comment: Have you tried something? Like counting how many things they do contain?

Comment: I tried all join types many times but couldnt do it :( Also i am newbie a bit.

Comment: I need group by companies, not contains (or not exists) total product counts from order list. I need also like operator. Thanks everyone :(

Comment: Read this, it may help you improve the quality of your questions: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry @MJH i couldnt. May you help over sqlFiddle? Actually its not difficult but i couldnt unfortunalety..

Comment: Looks like homework with not effort to me

Comment: @paparazzo be sure not homework :) Just i have summarized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the number of products for a company from the total number of products:

```
with    products as
        (
        select  P_ID
        ,       C_ID
        from    CompanyProducts
        join    Orders
        on      P_Name like '%' + O_Name + '%'
        )
select  c.C_ID
,       (select count(distinct P_ID) from products) - count(distinct P_ID)
from    Companies c
left join    
        products p
on      c.C_ID = p.C_ID
group by
        c.C_ID
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae847/2/0)

Comment: thank for answer but how can i entegrate in your query **Orders** table. I need to use like operator.

Comment: There's no reference to `O_ID` in the other two tables. How is it supposed to be integrated?

Comment: I will match as this: **lower(Order.O_Name) like '%' + CompanyProducts.P_Name + '%'**

Comment: Ok, I thought one was an order name and the other a product name. You could join them in a `with` statement so you don't have to join twice. SQL Server's `like` is case-insensitive by default, so no need to `lower`.

Comment: The important point is entegrating with Orders.O_Name column. As you see the values not clearly. comp, mou .. etc.

Comment: thanks for this trip: **like is case-insensitive**. Caused by im newbie i couldnt use **with** statement. May you continue on your sqlFiddle shortly. Thank you really!

Comment: I tried your solution but there is a gab. If an Order is not exists in CompanyProducts then not count this situation. May you look at this please: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7668/2

Comment: Just change (select count(distinct P_ID) from products) to isnull((select count(distinct P_ID) from products), 0)

Comment: Thank you @Andomar and jigga.. ok